# Вывести информацию, которая находится в админке на странице пользователя?

Tags: wordpress

Столкнулся с задачей, где требуется вывести информацию, которая находится в админке меню Users. Вот скрин, что нужно вывести[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Тут два вопроса. Первый - как её вывести? И второй - как её разместить на сайте в определенном месте? На сайте используется конструктор Elementor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы получить текущего пользователя используйте `global $current_user;`.

Чтобы получить пользователя по ID:

```
$user_id = 10;
$user = get_user( $user_id );
var_dump( $user );
```

Остальную информацию можно получить через `get_user_meta`:

```
$some_meta = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'meta_name', true );
var_dump( $some_meta );
```